# Flutter RenderFlex overflow crash

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-windows, flutter-linux

Is there a way to prevent RenderFlex overflow, if the canvas becomes too small?
This does not only apply to web but all devices.

Say a user resizes a browser window to 0 height, the "app" will crash.

Edit: Looking for a global solution, something like:

```
runApp(IgnoreRenderFlexOverflowApp(child: SomeWidget));

class IgnoreRenderFlexOverflowApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  IgnoreRenderFlexOverflowApp({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Some app title',
      home: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return SizedOverflowBox(
            size: Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight),
            child: child,
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Code is too big. Looking for a global solution like: runApp(IgnoreRenderFlexOverflow())

Comment: it's hard to help you without code. if you use GitHub, share your project link here.

Comment: Sample in edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
sinkWrap :true
```

Just Add this your problem will be solved by this